# Has anyone discovered any compatibility issues between ArcGIS 10 clients editing older ArcSDE geodatabases (e.g 9.3.x)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, versioning, arcgis-9.3

I’ve read the ESRI documentation here:  http://goo.gl/UUSM (link to ESRI) and http://goo.gl/TsmV  (link to ESRI) , so I know the documentation states that you can.  And I’ve actually edited data (a very small amount) in a 9.3 ArcSDE with no problems.

For those who are actually producing & maintaining on their versioned 9.3 geodatabases with ArcGIS 10 clients, have you experienced any issues?   Or has it been a relatively smooth experience (i.e works as advertised)?

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=17&MetaID=1807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, I've used ArcMap and ArcGis Server 10 for various editing tasks with no real problems on sde9.3. Obvioulsy the new v10 features are not available in sde9.3, but otherwise it's been very solid.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS 10 applications are all compatible with down-level versions of SDE (SDE 9.2 and higher as your links also indicate). Your only limitation should be the lack of options that require features only supported in the geodatabase at 10 such as e.g. feature attachments. If any problems were to be encountered, and I haven't heard of any, I'd log a bug with Esri tech support.

(disclaimer: although I am an Esri employee this is my personal experience and no guarantees are implied)

Answer (score 1):

We have an issue editing with ArcMap 10 to a 9.3.1 Oracle SDE database.  The issue is when the dataframe is in a different coordinate system than the feature layer being edited (which I know this is a big no, no... but never had this issue with 9.3).  It doesn't seem to project the data when inserting into the database.  Then the domain of the feature class gets all messed up... I submitted this to ESRI, never really heard anything much.